# Quiero mostrar cuantas veces se repite un mismo caracter con punteros ¿algo en mente?

Tags: c, punteros

Alguna ayuda que me puedan brindar, el problema me lo da al comparar `strcmp(cadena,letra_a_contar)`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
    int busqueda(char *cadena, char letra_a_contar, int tam)
        
    {
        int acc = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < tam ; i++) {
            if (strcmp(&cadena,&letra_a_contar)) {
                acc = acc+1;
            }
        }
        return acc;
    }
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        char cad[9];
        int tam;
        int buscar;
        int res = 0;
        
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Escribe la frase:\n");
        scanf("%s",cad);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Cuantas letras tiene la frase:\n");
        scanf("%i",&tam);
        printf("Escribe la letra que quieres contar:\n");
        scanf("%s",&buscar);
        res = busqueda(cad, buscar, tam);
        printf("%i", res);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: por que no utilizas `fgets()` para obtener, pues `scanf` solo lee hasta que encuentre un espacio

Comment: Que problema te da?

Comment: Christian en cada uno de los scanf los reemplazo con fgets?

Comment: gbianchi me dice que la comparación necesita mas argumento

Comment: pone el error completo por favor. y tu funcion busqueda, no hace nada de nada, porque siempre compara lo mismo....

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres un puntero hacía un puntero? (En el strcmp). ¿Y no será más fácil usar un simple == ?

Comment: Usar `strcmp` es incorrecto en este caso. Puedes hacer `cadena[i] == letra_a_contar`.

Answer (score 0):

Como comenta @pablochaches en un comentario... Estás intentando comparar una cadena completa con el valor de un carácter en particular, y lo estás haciendo una y otra vez ya que dicha comparación la incluyes en un bucle `for`. Y como comenta @Christian, te recomendamos utilizar `gets` para obtener tu cadena, ya que `scanf` se detiene al obtener un espacio.

Quieres comparar carácter a carácter, por lo que **debes comparar el valor de cada carácter uno a uno**.
Para ello tu función de búsqueda debería ser:

```
int busqueda(char *cadena, char letra_a_contar, int tam)
{
    int acc = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < tam ; i++) {
        if (cadena[i] == letra_a_contar) {
            acc = acc+1;
        }
    }
    return acc;
}
```

También, como mejora podrías incluso sustituir el bucle `for` por un `do-while` que detecte el fin de la cadena (carácter `\0`) y así no tener que introducir el tamaño exacto de la cadena. Sería una forma de hacer un programa más versátil y eficiente, pero es tan solo una idea.

**PROGRAMA CON DO-WHILE**

Te dejo por aquí cómo haría la implementación del programa sin tener que pedir cuántos caracteres tiene la cadena (OJO! como máximo tendrás 9 caracteres, ya que has limitado el tamaño de tu cadena a 9):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#define num_chars 9
int busqueda(char *cadena, char letra_a_contar)
{
    int acc = 0, i=0;
    do {
        if (cadena[i] == letra_a_contar) {
            acc = acc+1;
        }
        i++;
    } while (cadena[i]!='\0');
    return acc;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char cad[num_chars];
    int tam;
    int buscar;
    int res = 0;
    
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Escribe la frase:\n");
    gets(cad);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Escribe la letra que quieres contar:\n");
    scanf("%s",&buscar);
    res = busqueda(cad, buscar);
    printf("Hay %i letras %c", res, buscar);
    return 0;
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, un saludo

Comment: [gets](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) is unsafe...

Answer (score 0):

La función `strcmp` es para comparar cadenas (*strings*) como su nombre indica: *`str`ing `c`o`mp`are*.

Tú no quieres comparar cadenas, quieres contar letras:

```
int cuenta(char *cadena, char letra_a_contar, int tam)
//  ~~~~~~ <--- No estás buscando, estás contando.
{
    int contador = 0;
    for (int indice = 0; indice != tam ; ++indice) {
        contador += (cadena[indice] == letra_a_contar);
/*               ^^ <--- En C, las expresiones booleanas devuelven un cero (0) en caso
                         de que la expresión sea falsa y uno (1) si es verdadera. */
    }
    return contador;
}
```

Puedes ve el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDBboMwDD2Tr/CYKmAw1Dtjt922L6imyktMGwmcLiSTtqnfzgy0Pexk@9l@z8/6UffIh2m6t6z7aAiexmCsq4/PSlkOoCNxwFwf0cODRkOMFSxVT8HjHvfayYCvYJ4OOBTqVyXL5owb56GFbaOSTrJ8xi0bq2lBr/ldO29CA2W5IgUISXJjKFvIV@3d2n@Htv13QCEaZ5V4CtHzTbxR59XHgJbzL2fNct9ioPM40k6oIH1hiAx9PAgsP3hFeEOWoWqudPx2wG748CQBPqMl7wC18wb9QHVdp6J98iLT5ansLsSQbcYMgiUm2Big8YTaujGt1nZ1/eylyiCrYLQ/5LoVKorZ0cWOPPA8TX8)</kbd>.